# Multi Select List Boxes with Multiple Columns in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, multi-select

I have a listbox set to Multiselect property of Simple.
The listbox is populated by using a table.
There are 4 columns in the listbox

```
1    3/23/2014    4/5/2014    2014
2    4/6/2014     4/19/2014   2014
3    4/20/2014    5/3/2014    2014
```

The columns are PayPeriod, StartDate, EndDate, FiscalYear

What I want to be able to do is highlight a chunk of dates and have the first selected StartDate and the last selected EndDate populate two hidden text boxes so I can use them for my queries/reports.

I've tried a couple different ways.  Each time what happens is it only uses the last item I have selected in it's calculations.

```
Dim ItemIndex As Variant
For Each ItemIndex In Me.lstPayPeriods.ItemsSelected
    If Me.lstPayPeriods.Selected(ItemIndex) And Me.lstPayPeriods.Selected(ItemIndex - 1) = False Then
    Date1.SetFocus
    Date1.Text = Me.lstPayPeriods.Column(2, Me.lstPayPeriods.ListIndex)
End If
Next
```

In this example I tried to have it go through each Item of the listbox.  I wanted to check to see if the current row was selected and the row before it wasn't.  That way I could determine it was the first item selected in the group of selected items.  It would always only use the last item I had selected.

```
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
Dim FirstDate As Date

For CurrentRow = 0 To Me.lstPayPeriods.ListCount - 1
If Me.lstPayPeriods.Selected(CurrentRow) Then
    Date2.SetFocus
    Date2.Text = Me.lstPayPeriods.Column(3, Me.lstPayPeriods.ListIndex)
End If
Next CurrentRow

For CurrentRow = 0 To Me.lstPayPeriods.ListCount - 1
If Me.lstPayPeriods.Selected(CurrentRow) And Me.lstPayPeriods.Selected(CurrentRow - 1) = False Then
    Date1.SetFocus
    Date1.Text = Me.lstPayPeriods.Column(2, Me.lstPayPeriods.ListIndex)
End If
Next CurrentRow
```

I tried to do something similar with this code.  Again, it only uses the last item I have selected.

I am running into a wall figuring out how to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your approach. I'm personally not keen on the approach you're using to determine the earliest start and latest end, though the issue might just be your column numbers: the first column in a listbox is column 0, and the last column (of 4 columns) is column 3. Accordingly in your code above, you're setting Date2 = fiscal year, not enddate.

I would however recommend a different approach to determining (a) the earliest selected StartDate, and (b) the latest selected enddate. You could have a loop for each operation, or your can encapsulate both in a function:

```
private function GetPayPeriodDate(baseValue as Date, findLater as boolean, colNo as long) as Date
    'baseValue is the default date to test against
    'findLater tells the function whether to look for < or > the baseValue
    'colNo tells the function which column of data to test

    Dim vv as variant
    For each vv in lstPayPeriods.ItemsSelected
        if lstPayPeriods.Selected(vv) then
            if findLater then
                if lstPayPeriods.Column(colNo, vv) > baseValue then
                    baseValue = lstPayPeriods.Column(colNo, vv)
                end if
            else
                if lstPayPeriods.Column(colNo, vv) < baseValue then
                    baseValue = lstPayPeriods.Column(colNo, vv)
                end if
            end if
        end if
    next vv
    GetPayPeriodDate = baseValue
end function
```

Then you can set your start and end date textboxes by calling this function:

```
me.StartDate = GetPayPeriodDate(CDate("31/12/2099"), false, 1)
    'since startdate looks for the earliest date, the base date must be in the future
me.EndDate = GetPayPeriodDate(CDate("01/01/1900"), true, 2)
    'similarly, looking for the latest date, base date must be in the past
```